# can i fill two tables in method in Entity Code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

can i fill two table in below code?
Address , Cod ,Cost should be fill in tbl_Reciver.
but Lname , Name , Tell should be fill in Tbl_Sender.
can i fill two table here?

```
    public static bool InsertInTables(string Address, string Cod, int? cost,string Lname, string Name, string Tell )

        {
        MyContext db = new MyContext();
        try
        {

           //Can i fill Tbl_Sender like tbl_Reciver here 
            var tbl1 = new tbl_Reciver

            {
                id = MaxIdInTbl (),
                Address_s = Address,
                Cod_s = Cod,
                Cost_s = cost,

                  //i wanna fill below fields in tbl_Sender
                  // Lname_s = Lname,
                  // Name_s = Name,
                  //Tell_s = Tell,


            };

              //is it possible i fill two tables ?
            db.tbl_Reciver.Add(tbl1);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return true;

        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just.. add it? You can add to multiple `DbSets` in a single method, yes. Have you tried it first?

Answer (score 0):

`SaveChanges` does all of this for you when it sees that both are new and that they are related. It also uses the model’s mappings to figure out which is the dependent entity and needs the foreign key . With this information, it executes the database inserts in the correct order.

Note:if you create context using DbFirst approach for exist database its automatically generate the model as well.

but code first approach if you have any constrain you should define the model using override following method.

```
protected virtual void OnModelCreating(
    DbModelBuilder modelBuilder
)
```

then you can save your entities with same transaction.if any failure automatically rollback the transaction itself.

```
      Using(MyContext db = new MyContext())
      {
        try
        {
            var tbl1 = new tbl_Reciver
            {
                id = MaxIdInTbl (),
                Address_s = Address,
                Cod_s = Cod,
                Cost_s = cost,
            };

            long maxId=MaxIdInTbl();
            var tbl2= db.tbl_Sender.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == maxId);

            tbl2.Lname_s = Lname;
            tbl2.Name_s = Name;
            tbl2.Tell_s = Tell;

            db.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins,tbl2);
            db.tbl_Reciver.Add(tbl1);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
```

Comment: but how can i say : go to record on Tbl_sender that it's id_reciver is MaxIdInTbl () , and then do var tbl2= new tbl_Sender
                { Lname_s = Lname,  Name_s = Name,Tell_s = Tell, };

Comment: can you share the MaxIdInTbl () implimetation.i didnt get you

Comment: MaxIdInTbl () | what does this function is it db call or ?

Comment: it is a usuall fields in tbl_sendern that filled before.and i wanna fill Lname,Name,Tell now .i wanna say find record that it's id is   MaxIdInTbl and now fill Lname,Name,Tell.

Comment: i updated the above answer you want to update tbl_sender and insert tbl_Recive so try with above code it should be work.if your context is DbContext then replace 
db.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins,tbl2); 
with
context.Entry(tbl_sender).State = EntityState.Modified;